# Structure binding doesn't work without type?

Tags: c++, binding, c++17

I try to do something like this

```
pair<int, int> f() {
    return {1, 2};
}

int a, b;
[a, b] = f();
```

and get compilation error. All errors boil down to that fact, that the compiler think that it is a syntactically incorrect lambda. So if I use structured binding I always should write `auto`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's just how [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) work. It introduces *new* identifiers, so they cannot be existing variables. So when using it, you must use `auto`, e.g.

```
auto [a, b] = f();   // can also be auto&, auto const, etc
```

If you want to use existing variables, you can use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
int a, b;
std::tie(a, b) = f();
```

Note that *all* the identifiers must be new, so you can't mix and match these 2 approaches. e.g. you can't use a structured binding with a single already existing variable.